# retrieve :id attribute in controller after saving into db, rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, parameters

hello i was wondering if it was possible to retrieve the :id (the primary key that auto-increments in the db) after it gets saved? i have in my favorite_relationships controller

```
def create
    @lesson = Lesson.find(params[:favorite_relationship][:lesson_id])
    current_user.favorite!(@lesson)
    #params[:id] = ...
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to @lesson }
      format.js
    end
end
```

when current_user.favorite! gets called, it goes to my user model

```
  def favorite!(lesson)
    favorite_relationships.create!(lesson_id: lesson.id)
  end
```

however, is there a way to retrieve the :id the favorite_relationship is getting saved as? i wanted to set it in the commented out line

```
#params[:id] =
```

i need to specify a params[:id] for a gem im using

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are looking for favorite_relationships.id? in this case modify you controller to strore the value in the variable as

```
favorite_relationships = current_user.favorite!(@lesson)
params[:id]= favorite_relationships.id
```

Answer (score 1):

copy from [railsforum](http://railsforum.com/viewtopic.php?id=19345)

say your table name is table_A

```
@a = table_A.new()
@a.first = "firs name"
@a.last = "last name"
@a.save
```

To GET LAST INSERT ID OF table_A just use @a.id

@a.id will return the last insurted id of table_A